Can't dd broken SSD
When trying to sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=dump.dd conv=noerror,sync on my Kingston SSD (SA400S37/120G, SBFK71E0) the dmesg log shows the following:
 usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
 usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 usb 4-4: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
 usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Ugreen
 usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832456
 scsi host0: uas
 scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SATAFIRM    S11           0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
 sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
 
...

 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 6e a0 00 04 00 00
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 e2 a0 00 04 00 00
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 30 inflight: CMD IN 
 ...
 scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
 usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: device firmware changed
 scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED err -19
 sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
 sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
 ...
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=31s
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 ce a0 00 04 00 00
 I/O error, dev sda, sector 52896 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 2
 ...
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=31s
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 7a a0 00 04 00 00
 I/O error, dev sda, sector 31392 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 2
 sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
 usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 3412, async page read
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 3412, async page read
 ...
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
 usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 usb 4-4: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
 usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Ugreen
 usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832456
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 scsi host0: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
 usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd

I disabled UAS since "uas_eh_abort_handler" implies some issue related to it. After dd again I got the following:
 usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
 usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 usb 4-4: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
 usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Ugreen
 usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832456
 usb 4-4: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 1153: 800000
 scsi host0: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
 scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SATAFIRM    S11           0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
 sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
 usb 3-1.4.1: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: device firmware changed
 usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 6
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=31s
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 4f fb 28 00 01 00 00
 I/O error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 4f fc 28 00 01 00 00
 I/O error, dev sda, sector 5241896 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 4f fb 28 00 00 08 00
 I/O error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 5241640 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655205, async page read
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655206, async page read
 Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 655206, async page read
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
 usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 usb 4-4: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
 usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Ugreen
 usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832456
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 1153: 800000
 scsi host0: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
 usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 7
 usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
 usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 usb 4-4: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
 usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Ugreen
 usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832456
 usb 4-4: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 1153: 800000
 scsi host0: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
 scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SATAFIRM    S11           0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
 sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
 usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: device firmware changed
 usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
 sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
 usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
 usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
 usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 usb 4-4: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
 usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Ugreen
 usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 26A1EE832456
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 4-4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 1153: 800000
 scsi host0: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
 usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd

So the problem still remains. Someone has an idea what's going on and can help me?
Also I'm interested why actually UAS is used and in the log it says about Attached SCSI even though it is a SATA.

That looks like a SSD USB caddy. Try a different brand (not ugreen). I've had good experiences with rshtech, for example

use ddrescue instead of dd... dd conv=noerror,sync corrupts your data

Do you get the same errors if you remove the caddy and use only the SSD? If so, then that indicates an issue with the SSD itself and continuing to use it will increase wear.

@NasirRiley Sorry maybe stupid question but how do u mean "use only"? You mean straight to motherboard with a SATA cable? With laptop I only have USB interface.

@frostschutz thank you for pointing out!

Then you can't do what I mentioned. Your question doesn't indicate that it is a laptop.
